# Is it possible to pass a variable from a beforeEach/beforeAll function to my tests? (Pest php)

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, php-pest

Right now I'm rewriting some unit tests to use Pest and noticed every test creates a new user. The tests need the id that creating the user returns. I would like to know if it is possible to put this in the beforeEach function Pest provides so I can access this user id in my tests.

I would like to access $user within my tests, is this at all possible? If so, how? I noticed how in Javascript with Jest (which is similar) you can initialize the variable before the BeforeEach, but this does not work in php it seems.

Help would be appreciated!

```php
beforeEach(function () {
    $user = User::factory()->create();
});

test('Test that it shows finished tasks of company', function () {

// Do something with the user variable

//assertion

});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the documentation at https://pestphp.com/docs/setup-and-teardown#beforeeach

> As usual, the `$this` variable in the `beforeEach` function is bound to the current *Test Case object*. Therefore, you can share data with both it and test functions.

```php
beforeEach(function () {
    $this->user = User::factory()->create();
});

test('Test that it shows finished tasks of company', function () {

// You should have access to the user variable as a property:

dump($this->user);

// assertion

});
```

Comment: Thanks man, I must have skipped over that part!

Comment: Thanks Jesse for taking the time to write a detailed and clear question. Cheers.